# Issues with form submission

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation

A few questions here i have to ask, first of all, does it matter whether you put in your form:

```
<form action="whatever.php" method="post">
```

instead of:

```
<form name="" action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" method="post">
```

i mean i am just listing the whatever.php because it splits up my code instead of having massive files of code, and i just pass my error messages etc with session variables and then destroy them instantly, i was just curious as to what the advantages or disadvantages are and if i could be doing it better?

Next question is with form validation, i was told if it is not coming from a database, do not bother with server side validation and only bother with client side validation... this seems a bit odd to not bother with server side validation, i feel like i should be having both regardless of a database or not.

Comment: If you will leave `action=""` empty, form will vall self document.

Comment: The difference between `action="whatever.php"` and `action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"` is that the first makes a call to a file outside the originating form, while `self` or `""` as M1K1O stated, is done on the same page. That is for standard forms. Then you have Ajax forms, where action is not required (or left blank) and the form's name is usually the Ajax trigger function. Client-side validation should always be used, as opposed to JS because JS can always be disabled.

Comment: @Fred client-side validation is implemented in JavaScript so I'm sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen If using Ajax, yes.

Comment: @Fred I'm still confused. You can have client-side validation without ajax. Like validating a postal code; don't need ajax for that.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Exactly. I'm trying to see if I might not have explained it correctly. *Re-reading my comment now* lol

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Have a look at [**This Ajax Example**](http://teachingyou.net/php/simple-php-contact-form-using-ajax/) where the form's `ID` (mycontactform) is used to trigger PHP `$.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform")` that is what I meant. That answers your question to Frits. `send.php` will hold the code/function for `mail()` etc.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I pasted the same for the OP, disregard the `That answers your question to Frits` part in the above said comment (lol)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Ok, I re-read this thread, and found that there was a "communication breakdown" (not, The Led Zeppelin song, however it's a good one). What I meant was that, client-side validation is not efficient as it is for server-side and that validation can be bypassed if JS is disabled. I always use server-side validation. Ajax uses JS in conjunction to work, and there should be a server-side option if JS is disabled. I hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

The action in your form doesn't really matter too much. If you're using a framework with a router the URLs don't map directly to PHP files. Where your code lives shouldn't be determined by the URL, but this is when you get into more advanced code architecture.

> if it is not coming from a database, do not bother with server side validation and only bother with client side validation

It's the other way around. Values from the database are *safe*, user input is *never* safe.

Comment: say i leave it blank and my php script is in another file, how do i link it considering i have removed the action? like what is the proper way to link it to the form page?

Comment: @user1265535 That's where Ajax comes in. It usually uses the form's name to trigger the action to your PHP script, as stated from my original comment under your question.

Comment: Where did ajax suddenly come from?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen It's just another option I thought I would mention, from what the OP asked you in a comment to your answer.

Comment: @user1265535 Have a look at [**This Ajax Example**](http://teachingyou.net/php/simple-php-contact-form-using-ajax/) where the form's `ID` (mycontactform) is used to trigger PHP `$.post("send.php", $("#mycontactform")` that is what I meant. That answers your question to Frits. `send.php` will hold your code/function for `mail()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

> , i was told if it is not coming from a database, do not bother with
>   server side validation and only bother with client side validation..

**Wrong!** Everything that is done on a client side is potentialy dangerous. By disabling javascript or vbscript (or whatever) the user can bypass any validation. Always validate on the server side! Also consider Chrome & Firefox web developer tools, any HTML code can be changed on the fly.

As of the form, omitting action parameter or leaving empty(later is better as otherwise W3C validation fails) will tell the browser to send the input to the same file

Consider a following example

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $_POST['text'];
}
?>
<hr>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" value="susbmit">
</form>
```

The script will echo what is passed to it on a form submit

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in your form, the action attribute will default to the current URL. It's a way to tell PHP to *submit form to the place it came from*.

However, the same effect can be achieved by leaving the `action` attribute empty. The form will submit to itself. I personally think this is better. If you use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, it will be very easy for an attacker to inject malicious code by appending the `file.php` part of the URL. Leaving the `action` attribute empty can prevent this from happening.

Coming to your second question,

> i was told if it is not coming from a database, do not bother with server side validation and only bother with client side validation

No, that's the other way round. Values from database are usually safe, since it's you who inserted them to the database. On the other hand, user inputs should **not** be trusted and they should be validated correctly.